# не могу манипулировать значениям вложенного словаря потому-что разные ключи

Tags: python, словари

```
list_b = {'26002622': [{'counters': {'engine_hours': 17090610, 'mileage': 49272782, 'bytes': 56226445}}, {'lls': {'3': {'value': 195.942028986, 'filled': 0, 'timeDiff': 1671861696, 'latDiff': 0, 'lonDiff': 0}}}], '22904647': [{'counters': {'engine_hours': 51313246, 'mileage': 108255924, 'bytes': 173823294}}, {'lls': {'5': {'value': 297.583892616, 'filled': 0, 'timeDiff': 1671841582, 'latDiff': 0, 'lonDiff': 0}}}]


for i in list_b:
    print(list_b[i][1]['lls'])
```

результат кода:

```
{'3': {'value': 195.942028986, 'filled': 0, 'timeDiff': 1671861696, 'latDiff': 0, 'lonDiff': 0}},
{'5': {'value': 297.583892616, 'filled': 0, 'timeDiff': 1671841582, 'latDiff': 0, 'lonDiff': 0}}
```

Мне нужно чтоб вывел код значение вложенного словаря , то есть 'value'.
Пытался через .items() и .values() но дальнейшая манипуляция с данными не возможна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку у вас там словарь, то используйте метод `values()` к словарю.

```py
for i in list_b:
    for value in list_b[i][1]['lls'].values():
        print(value["value"])
```

вывод

```
195.942028986
297.583892616
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну дальше же у вас просто словари, от которых нужно вам взять значения с помощью `.values()` (ключи нас не интересуют, я так понял), и это будут тоже словари, а в этих словарях уже взять данные по ключу `value`:

```py
list_b = \
{'22904647': [{'counters': {'bytes': 173823294,
                            'engine_hours': 51313246,
                            'mileage': 108255924}},
              {'lls': {'5': {'filled': 0,
                             'latDiff': 0,
                             'lonDiff': 0,
                             'timeDiff': 1671841582,
                             'value': 297.583892616}}}],
 '26002622': [{'counters': {'bytes': 56226445,
                            'engine_hours': 17090610,
                            'mileage': 49272782}},
              {'lls': {'3': {'filled': 0,
                             'latDiff': 0,
                             'lonDiff': 0,
                             'timeDiff': 1671861696,
                             'value': 195.942028986}}}]}

for i in list_b:
    for val in list_b[i][1]['lls'].values():
        print(val['value'])
```

Вывод:

```
297.583892616
195.942028986
```

Можно и ещё немного код сократить, потому что и от словаря верхнего уровня вам ключи не нужны, а только значения:

```
for i in list_b.values():
    for val in i[1]['lls'].values():
        print(val['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный способ - обойти всю структуру рекурсивно:

```
def extract_value(x, lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for el in x:
            extract_value(el, lst)
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for k, v in x.items():
            if k == 'value':
                lst.append(x['value'])
            else:
                extract_value(v, lst)
    return lst


list_b = {'26002622': [{'counters': {'engine_hours': 17090610, 'mileage': 49272782, 'bytes': 56226445}}, {
    'lls': {'3': {'value': 195.942028986, 'filled': 0, 'timeDiff': 1671861696, 'latDiff': 0, 'lonDiff': 0}}}],
          '22904647': [{'counters': {'engine_hours': 51313246, 'mileage': 108255924, 'bytes': 173823294}}, {
              'lls': {'5': {'value': 297.583892616, 'filled': 0, 'timeDiff': 1671841582, 'latDiff': 0, 'lonDiff': 0}}}]}
print(extract_value(list_b))
```

```
[195.942028986, 297.583892616]
```